# Typescript decorators still experimental?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-decorator

I am going now through course on typescript.
There is a big portion of information about typescript decorators which were experimental on time of course recording - I believe that was few years ago.
Are this feature still experimental or going to be not the nearest time?

Comment: please read docs  on decorators https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: I think this is not experimental. Because of Angular use decorators. Also, decorators are one of the design patterns. So, maybe it is still in progress to improve it

Comment: @Kordrad You are right the main part of angular is `decorators` But  the official documentation clearly says it is experimental

Comment: Quite strange they are still experimental for so long..

Answer (score 0):

Based on official [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) the answer is **YES** it is experimental.

> Decorators are a stage 2 proposal for JavaScript and are available as an **experimental** feature of TypeScript.

Decorators are an experimental feature that may change in future releases.

Comment: Thanks @Alireza. Yeah, I saw this earlier in docs. Thought maybe somebody aware on some progress on that side.